# Calling SharedPreferences in didChangeDependencies

Tags: flutter

Can you call a boolean with Shared Preferences in didChangeDependencies?

I need to use `isToolTipTapped` as a conditional in my build method but it doesn't seem to be working..

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    isToolTipTapped = await checkIfToolTipTapped();
    print('$isToolTipTapped');
  
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  
  }


Future<bool> checkIfToolTipTapped() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool(SchnapConfigValues.toolTipTapped ?? false);
  }


print('$isToolTipTapped'); does return the boolean in didChangeDependencies method but my build method doesn't take the value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be try this code:

```
class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {
  static const TAG = 'DemoPage';
  bool isToolTipTapped;

  Future<bool> checkIfToolTipTapped() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool(SchnapConfigValues.toolTipTapped ?? false);
  }
  
  
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    checkIfToolTipTapped().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        isToolTipTapped = value;
      });
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isToolTipTapped == null) {
      return Your Loading Widget...
    } else {
      //Handle logic with isToolTipTapped
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {  
  static const TAG ='DemoPage'; 
  bool isToolTipTapped = false;
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

     Future<bool> checkIfToolTipTapped() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
     return prefs.getBool(SchnapConfigValues.toolTipTapped ?? false);  
   }
  
     @override  
   void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    checkIfToolTipTapped().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        isToolTipTapped = value;
      });
    });  
    }

     @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isToolTipTapped) {
      return Your Loading Widget...
    } else {
                    //Handle logic with isToolTipTapped
    } 
  }
}
```